# jQuery Ajax Post to WCF returning "Bad Request"

Tags: wcf, jquery

I can't seem to quite get this.

I have a WCF service like this;

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool Test();
```

Then the implementation;

```
    public bool Test()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Then my jQuery;

```
                jQuery.support.cors = true;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyService/Service/mex/Test",
                    timeout: 2000,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(9);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(status);
                        alert(error);
                    }
                });
```

Every time I call this I get "Bad Request".  If I change the URL to this say;

```
http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyService/Service/mex/Tesdt
```

i get the error "Unknown" so i think it's finding my service.

Answer (score 0):

You have `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` in your server method.

Yet in your AJAX call the `dataType` (that you are expecting back from the server) is `text`.

TLDR:

Change `dataType: "text"`  ----> `dataType: "json"`

Comment: Oop, sorry, pasted after a few tests.  The datatype of json also does not work.  Also, i cannot browse to it using say IE

Comment: of what?  the browser, if the service is not running says "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" and if the service is running i get an empty page

Comment: OK a couple more things.  What version of .NET are you running?  And also try putting a `data: {}` in your AJAX call.

Comment: .Net 4 and data: also has Bad Request

Answer (score 0):

You usually shouldn't send the request to the "mex" endpoint, unless you configured your web endpoint address to that. If your `webHttpBinding`/`webHttpBehavior` endpoint is at http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyService/Service, then the URI in your service should be just that.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyService/Service/Test",
    timeout: 2000,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(9);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(status);
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

Check that address, and if it doesn't work, please post your web.config and your global.asax.cs (if you're defining any routes)